# TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled creates cancellation

Tags: c#

Code below rises exception :

```
exception details: A task was canceled.
```

Just wandering why adding `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled` to parameter cancels task. Everything goes fine without this option. I was expecting that this option will executes code in case of something will cancel task. Looks like `OnlyOnCanceled` creates cancellation?

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("starting");
            Task<int> t = Task.Run(() => 42)
                .ContinueWith((i) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Canceled");
                    return i.Result * 2;
                }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled);




            Console.WriteLine("ending");

            try
            {

                Console.WriteLine("ret {0}", t.Result);
            }
            catch (AggregateException ae)
            {
                ae.Handle(ex => { Console.WriteLine("exception details: {0}",ex.Message);
                    return true;
                });
            }

            Console.ReadLine();



        }
```

Answer (score 5):

`OnlyOnCanceled` tells the second task which is defined in `ContinueWith` method to run only if the parent task is cancelled.

Since the first task is not being cancelled, the second becomes cancelled as it should not run.